# R, rMaps, datamaps: Moving the legend of a choropleth map

Tags: css, r, rcharts, datamaps, rmaps

I'm attempting to center the legend below a choropleth map of the United States ([an example of a generic map similar to what I've created](http://rmaps.github.io/blog/posts/animated-choropleths/fig/simplechoro.html)). I'm not very familiar with JS or CSS, but I poked around in the `datamaps.all.min.js` file located in the `R-3.2.1\library\rMaps\libraries\datamaps\js` directory hoping to be able to locate the tag for the legend and its default values. I found this:

```
.datamaps-legend dt, .datamaps-legend dd { 
  float: left; 
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;

} .datamaps-legend dd {
  width: 20px; 
  margin-right: 6px; 
  border-radius: 3px;

} .datamaps-legend {
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  z-index: 1001; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 4px; 
  font-size: 12px; 
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}
```

I changed it to this and included it in my `header.html` file:

```
.datamaps-legend dt, .datamaps-legend dd { 
  float: left; 
  margin: 0 3px 0 0;

} .datamaps-legend dd {
  width: 20px; 
  margin-right: 6px; 
  border-radius: 3px;

} .datamaps-legend {
  padding-bottom: 20px; 
  z-index: 1001; 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 40px; 
  font-size: 10px; 
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

}
```

It appears that these changes are either wrong or ineffective possibly because there is some other `.css` file taking precedence over these instructions. Currently, the relevant portion of the map looks like this:

[image]

The problems include *1) what to me seems like an inexplicable bold and italic treatment of the text* **edit: fixed that in my `.css` file** and 2) although `"position: absolute"`, the graphic flows over onto the tables below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I ended up doing, following the advice of [@markmarkoh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134441/markmarkoh), was to amend the template script `chart.html` located in `~\R-3.2.1\library\rCharts\libraries\datamaps\layouts` and change the very end of it from

```
<style>
.datamaps {
  position: relative;
}
</style>
```

to

```
<style>
.datamaps {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
.datamaps-legend {
  position: static;
}

.datamaps-legend dl {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>
```

then save the modified copy to my working directory and change the template location of the figure like this:

```
map1$setTemplate(script = 'chart.html')
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add some CSS to override the default styles, like so:

```
.datamaps-legend {
  position: static;
}

.datamaps-legend dl {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this just about got me there. I'm posting my answer in a moment.